# Is there any open source PDF form filler using c# except iText

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I am working on PDF form filler using c# code and iText library, but now the problem is iText library is no more an open source library. We need to buy license of AGPL. So I am looking for open source pdf form filler. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "iText library is no more an open source library" - iText is still open source. Because you can access the source. Open source. See? - "buy license of AGPL" - No, if you want to use iText along the lines of the AGPL, you don't need to buy anything. It merely requires you to make your product AGPL, too. If you don't want to fulfill the AGPL obligations, then you need an alternative license; iText offers a commercial license as alternative license. This is what you can buy. Furthermore, your question is a library recommendation request which is off topic on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I think you got something wrong there.

The AGPL license is still an open source license and is there to prevent the so called "application service provider loophole". As far as I understand, if you e.g. host software that is licensed under the GPL/that uses or modifies software licensed under the GPL you don't have to give out your source code. The AGPL prevents this.

Depending on what you want to do with your software you might aswell use iText.
But before doing so try to read up on the AGPL in order to prevent any legal mistakes.
The [AGPL FAQ](http://www.affero.org/oagf.html) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Still u cannot use it in commercial projects so this comment dont really help